# Is there a way to use a cell value to extrapolate multiple rows to new sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that requires me to load raw data from a file and split it into different sheets dependent on a value of a certain cell.

My current code is incredibly demanding on computer.

My current code is as follows:

```
Sub dataSplit()

Dim xRg As Range
Dim xCell As Range
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Range("AO2").Select
Do Until ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = ""


        If CStr(ActiveCell.Value) = "1" Then
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1030000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        ElseIf CStr(ActiveCell.Value) = "2" Then
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1030000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        ElseIf CStr(ActiveCell.Value) = "3" Then
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1030000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        ElseIf CStr(ActiveCell.Value) = "4" Then
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A1030000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        ElseIf CStr(ActiveCell.Value) = "5" Then
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("A1030000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        ElseIf CStr(ActiveCell.Value) = "6" Then
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet6").Range("A1030000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        ElseIf CStr(ActiveCell.Value) = "7" Then
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("A1030000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        ElseIf CStr(ActiveCell.Value) = "8" Then
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet8").Range("A1030000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        ElseIf CStr(ActiveCell.Value) = "9" Then
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet9").Range("A1030000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        ElseIf CStr(ActiveCell.Value) = "10" Then
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet10").Range("A1030000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        ElseIf CStr(ActiveCell.Value) = "11" Then
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet11").Range("A1030000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        ElseIf CStr(ActiveCell.Value) = "12" Then
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet12").Range("A1030000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        ElseIf CStr(ActiveCell.Value) = "13" Then
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet13").Range("A1030000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        ElseIf CStr(ActiveCell.Value) = "14" Then
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet14").Range("A1030000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        ElseIf CStr(ActiveCell.Value) = "15" Then
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet15").Range("A1030000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        ElseIf CStr(ActiveCell.Value) = "16" Then
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet16").Range("A1030000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        ElseIf CStr(ActiveCell.Value) = "17" Then
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet17").Range("A1030000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        ElseIf CStr(ActiveCell.Value) = "18" Then
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet18").Range("A1030000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        ElseIf CStr(ActiveCell.Value) = "19" Then
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet19").Range("A1030000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        ElseIf CStr(ActiveCell.Value) = "20" Then
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet20").Range("A1030000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        ElseIf CStr(ActiveCell.Value) = "21" Then
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet21").Range("A1030000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        ElseIf CStr(ActiveCell.Value) = "22" Then
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet22").Range("A1030000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        ElseIf CStr(ActiveCell.Value) = "23" Then
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet23").Range("A1030000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

           End If
            
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I know this is VERY rudimentary but it is completing the task, can anyone provide recommendations to how I can streamline this as you can probably tell my computer isn't very happy executing this code on a file with over 17,000 lines?

Overall the aim is to take all the rows with the number 1 and place it in a sheet with the same title, the same goes for all incremental numbers until there are no numbers remaining.

Comment: `ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet" & CStr(ActiveCell.Value)).Range("A1030000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)` works for all numbers. No `If`s needed.

Comment: Thank you! I just ran this and it has helped the scalability but it still uses a lot of computing to process. My computer gets really hot when i try to run this, do you think i'm simply asking too much of the system or is the code too bulky?

Comment: Well you can just use a filter. Filter by `1` then copy all filtered data to a new sheet at once (you'll find tutorials for that). That should be much faster than copy each row by row.

Answer (score 0):

Sean, this should work for you.  I am finding next distinct value and copying all for once per value.  BTW, you need to create sheets before running the macro.  Or add codes to create them automatically if not exists.

```
Sub Macro3()
'you need to sort data first
mysheet = ActiveSheet.Name
Range("A1").Select
myrow = ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row

Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(mysheet).Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(mysheet).Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "AO2:AO" & myrow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(mysheet).Sort
    .SetRange Range("A2:XFD" & myrow)
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

'find the next distinct cell and make copy operation as a bulk
j = 2
i = 3
Do While Range("AN" & j).Value <> ""
myVal = Range("AO" & j).Value
myNextVal = Range("AO" & i).Value
    
    If myVal <> myNextVal Then
        Range("A" & j & ":XFD" & i - 1).Select
        Selection.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet" & myVal).Range("A2")
        j = i
        i = i + 1
    Else
        i = i + 1
    End If
Loop

End Sub
```